# Android: Intercept onKeyDown() and onKeyUp()

Tags: java, onkeydown, intercept

I want to intercept key events from a hardware keyboard. For example when the users presses "a" I do not want that it is written in an EditText. Therefore I return true when the "a"-key is pressed and released but it is written in the EditText anyway. What is wrong?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            //Here it logs correct, but the letter appears in the EditText anyway
            Log.d("Textboard","A");
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            //Here it logs correct, but the letter appears in the EditText anyway
            Log.d("Textboard","A");
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onKeyXXX() of an activity is called later than onKeyXXX() of the EditText.

If you want to intercept it, just override the [dispatchKeyEvent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)).